# CTRL-V_CTRL-[key], instead of ^[key] gives ^[[27;5;[ASCII code of key]~ in xterm on Arch

Tags: key-bindings, terminal, terminal-buffer, linux-arch

For example, `Ctrl-v_Ctrl-w` gives `^[[27;5;119~` instead of usual `^W`.

It does behave in such way only on (*u*)*xterm*. I've tested it on *st*, *lxterminal*, *xfce4-terminal* and *rxvt*. I'm also 98% positive that it works fine on *konsole* and *gnome-terminal* (based on [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/e0fe1h/cttlr_ctrlw_doesnt_work_in_uxterm/)).

Furthermore, *xterm* on Ubuntu doesn't have issues. Only on Arch.

Outside Vim everything also is normal (i.e. `^W`). Neovim doesn't have such problem either.

Does anybody knows what could cause such behavior?

Specification:

- Distro: Arch Linux
- Kernel: Linux alpha 5.3.12-arch1-1
- xterm: 351 (but also occurs on 348)
- Vim: 8.1.2268-2 (and 8.1.2337-1)

[Related problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/e0fe1h/cttlr_ctrlw_doesnt_work_in_uxterm/)

While it's highly unrelated (`vim -u NONE` also doesn't work properly), but my configs:

- [vimrc](https://github.com/Jorengarenar/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/vimrc)
- [Xresources](https://github.com/Jorengarenar/dotfiles/blob/master/Xresources)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set t_TE= t_TI=
```

This in *vimrc* disables *modifyOtherKeys* (`:h modifyOtherKeys`), which was causing the problems

Comment: you actually want `:set t_TI= t_TE=`

Comment: @christian-brabandt You are absolutely right. I've made a typo. Already corrected. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As of patch [8.1.2350](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/fc4ea2a72d36de1196a3ce17352e72f8fe90f4bb), `Ctrl-V` will emit again the translated key, even if [modifyOtherKeys](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#modifyOtherKeys) has been set. To get the raw escape sequence, you can instead use now `Ctrl-Shift-V`